# Error while assigning a value in second case statement for interactive script

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a user interactive script. I am doing it by letting the user type the  values of the flags. My first case statement works fine but the second won't and I don't understand why? In the last two lines of this code I am suppose to see the values of my variables but I can only see the assigned value from the first statement and the second case statement give me no value. I have more case statements in my code but the first one is the only one that works. Do I need to do something in between statements?

```
echo "`tput bold`What machine was used?`tput sgr0`"
select Machine in "M1" "M2" "M3" "M4" "M5" "quit"
do
        case $Machine in
                M1) version=10;;
                M2|M5) version=15;;
                M4|M3) version=27;;
                quit) exit;;
                *) echo -e '\033[5;31;40mERROR: \033[0m\033[31;40mWrong option.\033[0m';;
        esac
        break
done


echo "`tput bold`Do you want to run default settings`tput sgr0`"
select settings in "yes" "no" "quit"
do
        case $settings in
                yes) run=1;;
                no) run=0;;
                quit) exit;;
                *) echo -e '\033[5;31;40mERROR: \033[0m\033[31;40mWrong option.\033[0m';;
        esac
        break
done

echo "Version: $version"
echo "Default settings: $run"
```

Comment: I copied your code and executed it with bash 4.2.45. Worked perfectly.

Comment: No issue in my test environment (GNU bash, version 3.00.16)

Comment: Thank you, I just needed to restart my computer :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be working fine. If you press 1 for each option, you get

```
Version: 10
Default settings: 1
```

Did you perhaps habitually press `y` instead of `1` to answer "yes"?

Comment: Thank you, I just needed to restart my computer :S